# Find the values $c\neq 1$ s.t. $E(c^{X})=1$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable s.t.
$$P(X=1)=p=1-P(X=-1)$$

I want to find the values of $c\neq 1$ s.t. $E(c^{X})=1$

I was able to appreciate a solution given in the following form

We can write

$$1=E(c^{X})=cP(X=1) + \frac{1}{c}P(X=-1)=cp+\frac{1}{c}(1-p)$$

And here is where my doubt comes in, why can we guarantee this? what theorem or what result does this tell us?. From this it is not difficult to notice that

$$pc^2-c+(1-p)=0$$

and solving for $c$ we have that

$$c_{1}=1$$ and $$c_{2}=\frac{1-p}{p}$$

And the value we are looking for seems to be $c_{2}$.

Any help for my question, any other alternative solution? I will be grateful!

Comment: Guarantee what?  You are asked to find $c$ that makes $\mathbb E(c^X) = 1$.  So you find what $\mathbb E(c^X)$ is, set it equal to $1$, and solve to find what $c$'s make the equation true.

Comment: I know that $P(X=1)+P(X=-1)=1$, but why can i say that $1=cP(X=1)+ \frac{1}{c} P(X=-1)$?

Comment: For a discrete random variable $X$ with values $x_i$, $\mathbb E[f(X)] = \sum_i f(x_i) \mathbb P(X = x_i)$.